# Is it possible for an HTML file to point to an external set of links?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm building a site that allows users to make games within it. I wanted to know if the in the main .html file, could I have a set file that has all the scripts and stylesheets and then link that file in my main .html file? It's kind of like:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="???package???" href="package.php">
    <title>Make a Game!</title>
</head>
```

**package.php**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="standard.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    ... etc ...
</head>
```

My main reason for doing it in PHP is so I can control if the current developer is premium or not and if they are, give them a couple more libraries to work with.

Comment: `include(package.php)` r remove the "head" from package

Comment: Actually, I totally forgot about that. You should post that as your answer so I can set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you just want to include one file in another so :

```
include 'package.php';
```

is all you need, remove the `<head>` `</head>` as you don't want them twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax you have to read that file with AJAX and set the output of  ajax wherever you want in your html.
But for that you have to echo your whole php file.